# No network access after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, qemu

I have a home server, which I just upgraded to 22.04. On it, I run a bunch of VMs and dockers for various services. I can access those services just fine, but if I try to ssh into the host, I get a timeout. If I ping it, no answer ever comes back. If I physically go to the server, plug in a keyboard and monitor, and try to ping the router(or some known-good IP like 1.1.1.1) from it, it cannot reach them. The server has a static IP address asigned through my router, just like all of the VMs and dockers. The MAC address does not appear to have changed.

I am officially out of ideas. What is my next step?

All of the VMs and dockers are bridged to the same physical interface the host itself uses to connect to my network.

Comment: Do you use VLAN tagging (IEEE 802.1Q) on host or VMs? What kind of virtual platform do you use? If I understood correctly, those VMs communicate well on the network, but their host itself does not have a connection. Please, can you enter these few commands on the host and a some VMs and paste their responses here at end of your question? Slashes mean a new line: ip add / ip route / ip neigh /

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the bridge-utils package:

`apt install bridge-utils`